# Linux Loadable Kernel Module exit_module

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I have an exit_module that needs to take a long time because it is freeing 1 TB of memory during the exit.  When I run the rmmod I get "stuck cpu" tracedumps from the kernel.

Is there a way to signify from the exit_module function that the module can not exit right now or a way to allow the rmmod to take a long time without getting the stuck cpu tracedump?

Answer (score 0):

touch_softlockup_watchdog() pets the watchdog.